# How can I check if a value in DB Columns is a BSN (Dutch SSN)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a way in which you are able to tell if values in your Column are valid BSN values. A BSN (Dutch SSN) has to conform to a sort of '11-test'. Mind you its not the same as a banking account. Checkout https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgerservicenummer for details.

What I would like to return is a zero or a one indicating if I have a valid (=1) or an invalid BSN (=0). Currently it is stored as a number.

I tried to make a SQL statement for this. I started with the following actions:

1. First I only want rows where I have an actual value and skipp the (null) values:

   ```
   SELECT D_BSN FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE D_BSN IS NOT NULL;
   ```
2. After that I want my BSN to be a VARCHAR2.

   ```
   SELECT TO_CHAR(D_BSN) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE D_BSN IS NOT NULL;
   ```
3. Now I want my BSN always to be of the same length:

   ```
   SELECT DECODE(LENGTH(TO_CHAR(D_BSN)),8, '0' || D_BSN, D_BSN)
     FROM EMPLOYEE 
    WHERE D_BSN IS NOT NULL;
   ```
4. Now if my length is not 9 I have an invalid field so 'exit' with 0.

   ```
   SELECT 
       DECODE(
       LENGTH(DECODE(LENGTH(TO_CHAR(D_BSN)),8, '0' || D_BSN, D_BSN)), 9,
       DECODE(LENGTH(TO_CHAR(D_BSN)),8, '0' || D_BSN, D_BSN), 0)
      FROM MW_DOCUMENTS 
     WHERE D_BSN IS NOT NULL;
   ```

At this point I find my SQL statement to become unreadable. Also because I have a long way to go. I have to pick each digit, multiply it by its position, sum up the result, divide it by eleven and see if the mod is equal to the last number of the BSN. This is easy in a programming language so why not put this in a function. So I could use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE IS_BSN(D_BSN) = 0
```

to get all the invalid BSN's. See my answer for what I came up with.

---

UPDATE: (added the code for the function)

---

Here is my Function that returns a zero or a 1 indicating valid or invalid BSN:

```
create or replace FUNCTION is_bsn(num_in NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS

-- Yes is BSN = True == 1 
-- NO not BSN = False == 0

 checkValue NUMBER := -1;
 factor NUMBER := 9;
 result NUMBER := 0;
 outcome NUMBER := 0;
 bsn VARCHAR2(9);
BEGIN
  bsn := to_char(num_in);
  -- Check if length is 8 if so add zero in front
  IF LENGTH(bsn) = 8 THEN
    bsn := '0' || bsn;
  END IF;
  -- Now length should be 9
  IF LENGTH(bsn) <> 9 THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
  checkValue := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(bsn, 9, 1));
  FOR Lcntr IN 1..8
  LOOP
    result := result + TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(bsn, Lcntr, 1)) * factor;
    factor := factor - 1;
  END LOOP;
  outcome := result mod 11;
  if outcome = checkValue then
    return 1;
  ELSE
    return 0;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 'FALSE';
END is_bsn;
```

UPDATE:

As Wildplasser answer was for Postgress and the original question was for Oracle I converted his answer for Oracle:

```
create or replace FUNCTION is_bsn2(inBsn in NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
-- Yes is BSN = True = 0 
-- NO not BSN = False  => 1
val NUMBER;
mul NUMBER;
bsn NUMBER := inBsn;
BEGIN
  val := 11 - (bsn mod 10); -- the check digit
  mul := 1;
  WHILE (bsn > 0) loop
     bsn := FLOOR (bsn / 10);
     mul := mul + 1;
     val := val + (bsn mod 10) * mul;
  END LOOP;
  IF (mul < 9) THEN
     RETURN 13; 
  END IF; -- too short
  RETURN val mod 11;
END;
```

Be aware that I renamed it to is_bsn2 and that the outcome is > 0 means NOT a valid bsn. I couldn't see much performance gain one over the other but I haven't tested it extensively.

Comment: What datatype is `D_BSN`? Looks like it might be a NUMBER and then you concatenate with it.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for ? You are asking for a function, then you post an answer to your own question with a working function.I really get lost in here.

Comment: OK - what is your question? You've posted some requirements and you've posted some code, but you have not indicated what the problems with the code might be. Please edit your question and tell us what the problem(s) are that your code is having - such as compilation errors, wrong results, etc - and perhaps someone can help. If you're getting wrong results, include examples. Thanks.

Comment: Yes its a number. I changed the initial question to make it more clear.
Until seeing wildplasser's answer I thought at first that working with a string would be easier, hence the conversion to string.

Comment: What is the purpose of using NUMBER as the datatype. It seems to me INTEGER is good enough here. (even better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can all be done in a single loop, without conversion to character.

- This version accepts an integer argument. (a nine digit decimal number should fit into a 32bit signed integer)
- it returns 0 on success, and > 0 otherwise (which makes more sense to me)
- There is no need to handle exceptions,since there is no possible exception.
- this is for postgres, but the differences should be minimal.

---

```
CREATE function bsn_invalid(bsn INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER
AS
$func$
DECLARE
        val INTEGER;
        mul INTEGER;
BEGIN
        val := 11- (bsn % 10); -- the check digit
        mul := 1;
        while (bsn > 0) loop
                bsn := (bsn / 10);
                mul := mul + 1;
                val := val + (bsn%10)*mul;
        end loop;
        if (mul < 9) then return 13; END IF; -- too short
        return val % 11;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
        ;

 -- test it::
SELECT bsn_invalid( 123456782);
SELECT bsn_invalid( 111222333 );
SELECT bsn_invalid( 23456784); -- assume a leading zero
SELECT bsn_invalid( 1234567);  -- too short
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that does not like functions; here is a solution embedded in a select statement:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM patient
WHERE bsn LIKE '%[0-9]%' AND (
    (9 * CAST(SUBSTRING(bsn, 1, 1) AS INTEGER)) +
    (8 * CAST(SUBSTRING(bsn, 2, 1) AS INTEGER)) +
    (7 * CAST(SUBSTRING(bsn, 3, 1) AS INTEGER)) +
    (6 * CAST(SUBSTRING(bsn, 4, 1) AS INTEGER)) +
    (5 * CAST(SUBSTRING(bsn, 5, 1) AS INTEGER)) +
    (4 * CAST(SUBSTRING(bsn, 6, 1) AS INTEGER)) +
    (3 * CAST(SUBSTRING(bsn, 7, 1) AS INTEGER)) +
    (2 * CAST(SUBSTRING(bsn, 8, 1) AS INTEGER)) -
    (1 * CAST(SUBSTRING(bsn, 9, 1) AS INTEGER))
) % 11 = 0
```

check the format of the field (nulls, value, etc) with
`WHERE bsn LIKE '%[0-9]%'`
then perform the actual 11 proef.

this works for practically any rdbm type. perhaps just switch CAST() with CONVERT() or something else depending on your db flavor.